# Laravel / NextJS CORS Issue

Tags: laravel, next.js, cors

I have been connecting my Laravel API backend to my NextJS frontend. Everything worked well until I put part of my NextJS app onto a subdomain and I immediately got CORS errors.

`"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://myapp.test:8080/dashboard' (redirected from 'http://myapp.test:8080/api/login') from origin 'http://app.myapp.test:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

http://myapp.test:8080/api/login receives data back, but when I set it to it's normally (working when on same domain) behaviour of redirecting to the main application, it throws the error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you tried the following method

//App\Http\Middleware;

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,Content-Type,X-Token-Auth,Authorization')
        ->header('Accept', 'application/json');
}
```

check config/cors.php

change paths array to * ('paths' => ['*'])

i hope it solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

As google says:

> Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a standard mechanism that allows JavaScript XMLHttpRequest (XHR) calls executed in a web page to interact with resources from non-origin domains. CORS is a commonly implemented solution to the same-origin policy that is enforced by all browsers.

[Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

An example of a cross-origin request, JavaScript code served from
`https://domain-a.com` uses ajax to make a request for `https://domain-b.com/data.json`

Now browser will block that request due to security.

### Solution

The solution is to send a header for some domains. An example of nginx:

```
location / {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

More secure option:

```
location / {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://app.myapp.test" always;
}
```

In laravel you can manually send headers or use middlewares

```
$request->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the env:

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS="${APP_URL}"
```